# The Mediterranean diet - statistics issues with the updated paper

Tags: hypothesis-testing, clinical-trials, random-allocation, statistics-in-media

In 2013, a group of researchers published a [paper](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1200303) with results on a randomized trial of the Mediterranean diet, finding that it appears to have significant health benefits.  Today, they retracted their original paper because of statistical errors and [published](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1800389?query=featured_home) a re-analysis of their data that corrects those errors, and still finds significant health benefits to the Mediterranean diet.

However, it appears some experts are not persuaded; the New York Times had [an article today](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/13/health/mediterranean-diet-heart-disease.html) quoting multiple researchers as saying that they remain skeptical and are not convinced the re-analysis fully addresses the statistical issues.  (The article also has an interesting summary of some of the challenges and [issues](https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2018/06/13/619619302/errors-trigger-retraction-of-study-on-mediterranean-diets-heart-benefits) with the original paper.)

What are the remaining concerns with the statistical analysis of the updated paper?

Answer (score 3):

The retraction and subsequent re-analysis of the 2013 paper on the Mediterranean diet by Estruch et al. have left some experts skeptical due to the issues surrounding the randomisation process in the study. The original claim that the Mediterranean diet was directly responsible for a reduction in heart attacks and strokes has been softened in the re-analysis, as it can no longer be supported due to flaws in the study's randomisation.

Here are the primary concerns regarding the statistical analysis in the updated paper:

**Non-Randomised Participants**: Approximately 14% of participants were not assigned randomly to the diet groups. In some cases, couples were assigned to the same diet, and in one instance, an entire village was assigned the same diet without informing the other investigators. This lack of randomisation undermines the study's ability to establish a cause-and-effect relationship between the diet and health outcomes.

**Softened Conclusions**: The re-analysis led to a softening of language regarding the conclusions. The revised paper only suggests that people following the Mediterranean diet had fewer strokes and heart attacks, as opposed to the original paper which claimed that the diet was the direct cause of these health benefits. This change indicates less certainty about the diet's effects.

**Impact on Credibility**: The randomisation issues and modified conclusions have affected the perceived strength of the evidence. The original publication in a prestigious journal like the New England Journal of Medicine (NEJM) gave the study a high level of credibility. The retraction may lead to questions about whether the NEJM would have accepted the paper if the randomisation issues had been apparent initially.

**Broader Implications**: This situation has broader implications for the credibility of scientific research, as it underscores the importance of rigorous randomisation procedures in clinical trials. Without proper randomisation, the risk of bias increases, and the ability to draw cause-and-effect conclusions is compromised.

While the authors of the retracted paper claim that the re-analysed results are consistent with their original findings, the issues with randomisation mean that a direct causal link between the Mediterranean diet and improved cardiovascular outcomes cannot be definitively established based on this study alone. Further research with rigorous randomisation would be required to substantiate the diet's health benefits with greater certainty.

Comment: To suggest that an individual is not randomized because they are a member of a randomized cluster as part of a cluster randomized study is incorrect. If you then say well an individual's randomization should be independent of other's randomization assignment - but that's not true either. Simplest example: permuted block randomization. Rather one should consider contamination, the tendency that attributes contributing to correlation inside clusters interact with average treatment effect to obtain a different estimate. Then, the cluster randomized effect is its own thing (still useful).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation!  Do you know of any sources where I can read more about the technical details?  e.g., papers/critiques of the statistics, from the critics who are raising the concerns about randomization?  I would imagine that assigning couples the same diet or even villages the same diet could be OK as long as it is taken into account in the statistical analysis?  I wonder if the criticism is that these forms of non-random selection weren't taken into account in the statistical analysis of the data?